# Translate entire Excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, translation

Does anyone have a function written or know how to translate an entire Excel sheet? Want to avoid doing this cell-by-cell, as I'm working with a lot of data. Also can't use third-party services as I'm handling sensitive information. I'm very much a newbie to Excel, so I probably won't be able to do anything complicated on my own.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/translate-text-into-a-different-language-287380e4-a56c-48a1-9977-f2dca89ce93f

Comment: Find & replace with a vba loop. Check out questions on here for vba etc